# connect git to Github account

Tags: git, github

Sorry for asking a lame question but I'm new to this and needed help.

I installed git on my laptop first and made an account on github later, how do I connect them now?

Many articles on net describe how to connect if github account is made first then git is installed but the other way round is not given.

I'm asking this because I've made a repository on my system but it is not showing in the github account even though both have the same email address.

Comment: Did you read the Github help?  (e.g. https://help.github.com/articles/create-a-repo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a new repository on github (cf the "New repository" button on Github main page)
2. Add this repository as a remote: `git remote add origin url/provided/by/github`
3. Push to this repository: `git push origin master`

Answer (score 7):

It is a good idea to set your local mail address to the same as on github.

```
git config --global user.email "hello@example.com"
```

GitHub uses the mail address to link your commits with your GitHub-account.

If you use https:// to push to your git repository you will be asked for your credentials.

Maybe these links will help you to understand more:

- https://help.github.com/articles/why-is-git-always-asking-for-my-password
- https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git

If this is your first time using Git you may test the GitHub Client for http://windows.github.com/ or http://mac.github.com/

Answer (score 2):

You need to link both the repositories.

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:caius/foo.git
```

like this:

```
git remote add origin <link to your github repo>
```

What you are doing is adding a remote repository to your local repository. Before you can do this, you need to create your corresponding repository on github that you wish to maintain.

You can then push to the remote branch from your local: `git push origin master`. This will reflect the changes you have made in the local repo in your github repo.
Here `master` refers to the local repo (master is the default branch you are on), and the `origin` is the remote branch - the one on github, that you have added.

I suggest you have a look at the [git documentation](http://git-scm.com/documentation) to get a hold of things. It's a better idea before you start doing anything major.